# Using matrix transformation for 3D image registration

Tags: python, image-registration

With python, when I make a registration with some programs (like Flirt from FSL library) for a reference and moving 3D images, I'm getting a transformation matrix and of course a resulting registrated 3D image. My aim is to use the transformation matrix to make the registration of the reference image "manually". Is there any function/tutorial/code which explain how to operate this ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "registration"?

Comment: classical definition : Image registration is the process of transforming different sets of data into one coordinate system. Having two images obtained from two different sensors,  registration will permit to overlay the second image on the first image. https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FLIRT